# How do I hang a device on this saddle box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, junction-box

I'm installing a pair of vanity lights in our new bathroom. One of them, conveniently, needs to mount directly over a stud which precludes installing a regular octagon box. Instead, I'll have to use a saddle box like this:

[image]
<sup>Click to embiggen. Source: [Lowes.com](https://www.lowes.com/pd/RACO-1-Gang-Black-Plastic-New-Work-Standard-Saddle-Boxes-Ceiling-Electrical-Box/1057119)</sup>

Installation of the box looks quite straightforward: Install the small screw (hidden behind the bolt visible at the front, then make pilot holes and drive the two larger bolts.

Once I've done that, though, I see *nothing* to attach either the ceiling fan they claim can be hung from this nor the wall sconce I plan to put on this. My light comes with an adjustable `x` shaped brace and some 8-32(?) screws that would *normally* go into the mounting holes in a "normal" octagon box like this:

[image]
<sup>Source: lowes.com</sup>

Note the holes on opposite corners. What I'm not seeing is the place to put the screws in the saddle box I'm going to have to use. What obvious thing am I missing?

How do I attach a wall sconce to this box once the box is on the wall?

Comment: The Lowes ad mentions attaching lights/fans to the stud.  Either this is just a box for wire connections or you need a cross piece attached to those two screws.

Comment: One type of crosspiece: https://www.amazon.com/Universal-Mounting-Diameter-Crossbar-Chandelier/dp/B08TGGZM21 (not endorsement)

Comment: That makes sense, @crip659. The light does come with a cross brace, but it looks like those screws are significantly too large for the holes it comes with. Maybe I'll have to take a look once I've got one in hand. Wanna write up an answer? You'll get my vote, and if it works, a check mark for your efforts... ;)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate my light comes with a bracket and some 8-32 (?) screws, just like that bracket. However, there are no holes in the box to put those screws into. I guess I wasn't clear enough in my question since you & crip both said nearly the same thing... I've edited the question to be more explicit. _I_ knew what I was asking, didn't you? :D

Comment: This is the first time even knowing about them.  The one on Lowes seems to have two mounting points for stuff, on the top sides which yours does not show.  Zoom in and does seem like mount points at those screws.

Comment: The two long screws will go through the linked *ring thingy* (that's the technical term, afaik) and you'll fuss and fiddle with getting the sconce attached with additional machine screws/nuts through other holes in the ring. Crystal? Or am I totally not getting it?

Comment: Sometimes the bar strap with the properly spaced and tapped holes for the sconce needs to be attached to the ring thingy.

Comment: @FreeMan -- do you know which make/model of saddle box you're using for this?

Comment: @FreeMan -- are you sure you aren't mixing it up with the pancake box 5000fingers mentioned? Because the specs on the saddle box in question say it's oh, 12.5 cu. in.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, @ThreePhaseEel. I looked up the capacity of the pancake box and had those numbers in my head. Frankly, hadn't checked the capacity of the saddle box! TYVM for the correction. I'll delete my original comment, so you may want to delete yours or it won't make sense. ;)

Answer (score 5):

The Ceiling fan mount or the fixture "X" brace goes under the 2 long screws pictured.  It's that simple.

Comment: This.  Sconce bolts to brace.  Brace screws to studs.  Toss the box bolts that come with the brace.  If there's no brace buy one.

Comment: This is what I was hoping for. However, I just picked up the box last night and haven't had a chance to install it yet, so I don't know if those bolts will fit through the x-brace that comes with the lights. I'll have to test that out before installation.

Comment: @FreeMan https://hubbellcdn.com/salesdrawings/7120.pdf has instructions inside it

Comment: Ahh... It's steps 2 & 3 that weren't obvious. Write that up as an answer, @ThreePhaseEel, and I'll happily give it a check mark as that is the solution. TYVM!

Comment: It all seemed so obvious to me.   I have to give better details.

Comment: @FreeMan -- written up with a link :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need this fan-rated box, it's overkill for a bath sconce. In this situation, as long as you have only one 14/2 cable coming in, you can just use a 1/2" pancake.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/4-in-6-cu-in-Metal-Round-Pancake-Box-56111-30R/202601207

Comment: Pancake boxes are very short on cubic inches, even compared to what volume exists inside a saddle box.

Comment: The fill rating for pancakes will accommodate one 14/2 conductor. And then there will always be more space inside the sconce. It will work fine.

Comment: Could be a lot here. Two lights (as stated in question), so could be as much as 1 14/2 coming in from panel, 14/3 to switch, 14/2 to 2nd light. And could all be 12/ if on a 20A circuit. So min. 1 x 14/2, max. 2 x 12/2 + 1 12/3. Big difference.

Comment: It is, in this case only going to be one 12/2 cable coming in, so this might actually be an option. I'll have to take a look. Thanks! Hrm... on second thought, a box fill calculator says one 12/2 requires 9 cu in, and the Raco 8293 pancake box is only 6 cu in. But... there's space in the canopy, so that just might work.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel ^ thoughts on fill requirements?

Comment: My mistake, didn't read carefully, I thought the photo was the actual install, so I assumed you were working with 14AWG. If this job is inspected, a pancake won't work for 12AWG. However if this circuit is 15A, and you can rewire the vanity sconces so that the one that falls on top of the stud will be the last in the circuit, you could use just one 14-2 wire, and a pancake.

Comment: Is this job permitted? If it wasn't going to be inspected, and especially if there is additional fill capacity in the sconce canopy, personally I'd feel comfortable using a pancake with one 12-2 cable. Realistically, how much more space would be required merely by using the 12-2 instead of 14-2?

Comment: @5000fingers  Even if this job is not inspected now, it probably will be some time in the future.  When it happens and an inspector sees this, can be sure they will go over the whole house with a fine tooth comb.  If there is one mistake with code, they will figure there are others.

Comment: Psst.. @5000fingers the image source is listed as "lowes.com" and links to the product listing there with that exact image. :D :D And yes, this is permitted new construction and will be inspected. Granted, our inspector is a somewhat lackadaisical good ol' boy and I doubt he'll be counting cubes, but, who knows. He was kind enough to give my plumbing an eyeball yesterday _before_ it was all glued together, and pointed out a couple of violations that will be easy to fix w/o glue. He noted that I'm using very oversize boxes for the electrical, too, and was impressed. (con't)

Comment: ... Don't know if the sudden appearance of a pancake box would really get his attention or not.

Comment: Also, no the fan rated saddle box is needed for its weight bearing capacity, but for its ability to put the sconce exactly where I want it.

Answer (score 2):

### You drive the mounting screws through the bracket and holes in the box into the joist

The way saddle boxes, like yours, work is that the fixture bracket is able to be mounted to the stud through the holes in the box using the mounting screws supplied with the box.  To do this, you use the fixture bracket as a template to mark and predrill for the holes after the box is mounted; you can then use the supplied screws to mount the fixture bracket, as detailed in [the instructions for your box](https://hubbellcdn.com/salesdrawings/7120.pdf).